# SSMS Obfuscation of string

Tags: sql, sql-server, obfuscation

I need to create a script to obfuscate some data.
The string is quite long and I need to obfuscate only some parts of it.

In the table the records are similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><CONTRACT><IBC IBC_REF="f45f1231234ae5ac2easdasdfde5dfd" IBC_TYPE="I" TELEPHONE_1="1111111" TELEPHONE_2="11111111" MOBILE_PHONE="11111111" E_MAIL="asdasdasd@hotmail.com" SOLICITATION_MAIL="0" ARREARS_MAIL="1" MAIL_REDIRECTED="0" TITLE="Mrs" SURNAME_REGISTERED_NAME="Assadasd"
```

And it needs to become like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><CONTRACT><IBC IBC_REF="f45f1231234ae5ac2easdasdfde5dfd" IBC_TYPE="I" TELEPHONE_1="Telephone-1" TELEPHONE_2="Telephone-2" MOBILE_PHONE="MobilePhone" E_MAIL="email-1" SOLICITATION_MAIL="0" ARREARS_MAIL="1" MAIL_REDIRECTED="0" TITLE="Mrs" SURNAME_REGISTERED_NAME="Surname"
```

How can I update all the rows of the table and change only some of the strings by saving the other words?

Comment: I'm using sql server

Comment: Are you asking how to update attributes of data stored in an XML column?

Comment: I just need a script to change/obfuscate only some of the words in the string for all the records in the column.

Comment: If you want to obfusavate specific words, why not use `REPLACE`? this doesn't look like that's what you want to do though, it looks like, as @DanGuzman suggests, you want to replace the values of the specific data elements in the XML.

Comment: I was thinking about using REPLACE but I'm not sure how to create a script to say REPLACE the value after TELEPHONE_1= and between the "" and then do it again for 6-7 more  strings.

Answer (score 0):

Seemingly you are working with XML strings, so I would suggest to use the SQL Server XML functionalities. Following a short example:

```
DECLARE @input NVARCHAR(4000) = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><CONTRACT><IBC IBC_REF="f45f1231234ae5ac2easdasdfde5dfd" IBC_TYPE="I" TELEPHONE_1="1111111" TELEPHONE_2="11111111" MOBILE_PHONE="11111111" E_MAIL="asdasdasd@hotmail.com" SOLICITATION_MAIL="0" ARREARS_MAIL="1" MAIL_REDIRECTED="0" TITLE="Mrs" SURNAME_REGISTERED_NAME="Assadasd" /></CONTRACT>';
DECLARE @x xml = CONVERT(xml, REPLACE(@input,'encoding="UTF-8"','encoding="UTF-16"'));

SELECT @x.value('(/CONTRACT/IBC/@TELEPHONE_1)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)');

DECLARE @y xml = @x

SET @y.modify('replace value of (/CONTRACT/IBC/@TELEPHONE_1)[1] with "TELEPHONE_1"');
SELECT @y.value('(/CONTRACT/IBC/@TELEPHONE_1)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)');
SELECT @y

DECLARE @output NVARCHAR(4000) = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), @y)
SELECT @output
```